# Open PDF files in Foxit reader in fullscreen mode with fit page width

Tags: foxit-reader

can we open pdf files in fullscreen in foxit reader wtih fit page width so that i dont have to press Ctrl+Numpad+ everytime to zoom in? Can this be done? Please Help.

Comment: Don't know how to open them by default. But instead of using `Ctrl+Numpad+` you can simply use the shortcut to fit pages by width that is `Ctrl+3`

Comment: @aimbire - but is the GUI hidden o get the real fullscreen view?

Answer (score 3):

Check for **Default Zoom** under *Page Display* in Foxit's Preferences.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've just created an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script [FoxItReader-tweaks.ahk](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/AutoHotkey-scripts/blob/master/scripts/FoxItReader-tweaks.ahk) that provides the following to shortcuts:

- F11: Views the PDF in *full-width* full screen.
- Left Ctrl-R: Reloads the current PDF document.